How I link a variable in a sub-agent to a dynamic variable in another sub-agent in Anylogic
I have an Agent let's say "A" on the main agent, then I have another agent let's say "B" inside agent "A", and I created a dynamic variable in agent "A" and I want to use its measures results in a dynamic variable equation in agent "B", how can I do that?
I tried linking the agents via the connections, but it only sends messages, and I want the dynamic variable to read a value, not a message, then I tried to move the variables to the main agent and use the (main.variablename) in both agents "A & B" it gave a syntax error and refused to run the model
I tried chat GPT as well, but it wasn't so much of a help, YouTube, and Anylogic's help.

Please check this explanation: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to. Then do all step-by-step tutorials first, they teach you this and many more concepts: https://anylogic.help/tutorials/index.html

In B, you can access your parent agent A using a.myDynamicVariable
Check for the small layer pointers AnyLogic creates for you, they look like this:
Also see https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to

please upvote useful comments @JasmineKhattab . Helps future users with similar problems, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote
